# Porting nodejs module to React Native: Object.prototype undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

**Here's my source tree at the exact moment of the problem:**

https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/tree/cf29b3cc90df7c5c7bb2d27c2205264d52b0715d/src/jscam

*I believe `npm install`, `npm start` and `npm run android` will make it launch (note that onvif is not installed from npm but cloned in npm `post-install` script and then installed, but it gets installed in `node_modules` with a symlink to the place where it cloned. I even tried to put everything in `node_modules` just in case, but the error persists). Also don't mind the extra docker things I have in the folder*

Anyways, the problem is:

I'm trying to use the nodejs module [onvif](https://github.com/lucaszanella/onvif) in React Native, so I used [this technique](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify) to translate the require methods using babel and installed [browserfy](http://browserify.org/) modules to implement the core nodejs modules. I've tested with simple examples like [crypto](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/blob/master/crypto_example.js) and it worked. However, when I try to simply import the onvif module I get this:

[image]

[Here's device.js line 30](https://github.com/lucaszanella/onvif/blob/0a9bebbb40d6cd3535638ad613bb95eeaba07fc9/lib/device.js#L30), looks like `Cam` is undefined here

When I import the `onvif.js` which imports `cam.js`, nothing happens. But then it imports `device.js` which seems to be getting undefined when importing `cam.js` again

I also tried [this method](https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify/issues/4) which seems to avoid all the babel translation but surprisingly the problem persists.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the new source tree: https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/tree/98b714219ed25b9d91ea3af275177f66fdb74fa2/src/jscam

I'm now using extraNodeModules which is the official way to do. You can see my dependencies here: https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/blob/98b714219ed25b9d91ea3af275177f66fdb74fa2/src/jscam/rn-cli.config.js

Now the error changed:
[image]

It's on this line: https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/d65e3bb5049893aaab4aba05198b9cd335b5a1ad/lib/sax.js#L222

It still looks like the same type of error though

**Update: if you get dgram not found, try**

```
npm install lucaszanella/react-native-dgram-shim
```

It is already in package.json, it should be installed but someone complained it didn't

Comment: Seeing last update,
https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/blob/d65e3bb5049893aaab4aba05198b9cd335b5a1ad/lib/sax.js#L222
Seems the module "Stream" is missing, same as previous error. Try to use one module. I dont think you need to ReactNatify ur own module. Write code directly and import in react-native.

Comment: @xdeepakv I didn't understand. In my rn file: https://github.com/lucaszanella/jscam/blob/98b714219ed25b9d91ea3af275177f66fdb74fa2/src/jscam/rn-cli.config.js the stream module is mapped. Why it didn't work?

Comment: 3rd bounty in a row?

Comment: @TarunLalwani really need it :(

Comment: I am using mac and the thing doesn't build only? I get module dgram not found in onvif

Comment: @TarunLalwani in package.json there is  "react-native-dgram-shim": "lucaszanella/react-native-dgram-shim". Don't know why it didn't install. Try a manual installation then, please. npm install lucaszanella/react-native-dgram-shim

Comment: So the current issue you have is because of `stream`. This can be fixed by changing to `stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')`. But doing that you will get back to your `Cam` undefined error. This is because the package `onvif` that you are using has a circular depedency. cam -> device -> cam. Node can handle cyclic dependencies but you need to fix it to get it working here

Comment: See this thread as well for help https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/961

Comment: @TarunLalwani You're right. After removing cylic dependencies: https://github.com/lucaszanella/onvif/commit/67238a64e0a7a727337c1724f64a8a8817cf6dde it worked. Please make it an answer so I can give you the bounty.

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity: why it didn't work with the official http-stream library from nodejs?

Comment: @LucasZanella, added the information about that in the answer. Glad your issue is finally solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are three issues I found

- `react-native-dgram-shim` needs to be copied as `dgram` in `node_modules`
- `stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify')` needs to be used in `rn-cli.config.js`. The stream module you had used didn't seems to define `Stream` object and `Stream.prototype` access caused an error
- The `onvif` module has `cam -> device -> cam`, this is handled well in `browserify`, `webpack` and `nodejs`. But the `metro` packer that `react-native` seems not like the cyclic imported. It means the `require.js` of the same needs to be fixed or the cyclic dependency needs to be removed

So you either make a fix to the `require.js` polyfill at `jscam/src/jscam/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js` or you change your files to remove cyclic imports by passing the required objects like below

```
require('./device' )  (Cam);
```

And update `device.js` like below

```
module.exports = (Cam) => {
```

And remove the

```
const Cam = require('./cam').Cam
```

This will make sure the cyclic dependency is removed and the module should then load fine

PS: On a side note, that is why its said perseverance wins. This was your 3rd bounty attempt and I watched the question go 2 last time in front of me. But your 3rd attempt motivated me to have a dive in and see if I could help you out.

Comment: thank you. I was lost about how to debug this. I had generated a big readable bundle file but it was too big. The cyclic dependency error is not much self explanatory but I'm glad you could see. Wish I could give more points, but I spent them all